# How to store a sql result to a variable in C# using Dapper.NET

Tags: c#, dapper, sqlconnection

I'm using [dapper](/questions/tagged/dapper) in my project, a beautiful tool for storing the `SQL query` results to a `List` and this working good.

I wrote a `SQL query` to fetch a record from database and store the result in a variable, I tried using **dapper** but stuck up with an error.  I've pasted the corresponding code.

> **Exception:** Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Dapper.SqlMapper+DapperRow]' to
>   type 'System.IConvertible'.

```
try
{
  using(var connection = ...)
  {
   connection.Open();
   const string masterSelectQuery = "SELECT Id as [fileId], FileName as [fileName], Frequency as [frequency], Scheduled_Time as scheduledTime FROM MASTER_TABLE";
   masterTableList = connection.Query<MasterTableAttributes>(masterSelectQuery).ToList();//Working fine

   const string lastProcessedTimeQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 file_transfered_time as [lastProcessedTime] FROM PROCESS_LOGS ORDER BY file_transfered_time DESC";
   DateTime lastProcessedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(connection.Query(lastProcessedTimeQuery)); //Here it fails
  }    
}
```

To overcome this error I used `SQLCommand` as follows

```
using (command = new SqlCommand(lastProcessedTimeQuery, connection))
{
  DateTime lastProcessedTime = (DateTime)command.ExecuteScalar();//working fine  
}
```

I am making a mistake in using dapper, can anyone please guide me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `connection.Open();`, Dapper will open the connection if it isn't already.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez that depends on which version is in use, but: yes

Comment: @ErenErsönmez You're right, thanks for pointing it.  I'm using .NET Framework4 with the corresponding dapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`connection.Query(lastProcessedTimeQuery)` returns a *sequence* of *rows*, each individually `dynamic`. Assuming `file_transfered_time` is a `datetime`, you have two choices here:

```
DateTime lastProcessedTime = connection.Query<DateTime>(
                 lastProcessedTimeQuery).Single();
```

or, to show how non-generic `Query` works with a `dynamic` row:

```
DateTime lastProcessedTime = connection.Query(
                 lastProcessedTimeQuery).Single().lastProcessedTime;
```

If your `PROCESS_LOGS` table could ever be empty, you might prefer `SingleOrDefault`:

```
DateTime? lastProcessedTime = connection.Query<DateTime?>(
                 lastProcessedTimeQuery).SingleOrDefault();
```

or:

```
var row = connection.Query(lastProcessedTimeQuery).SingleOrDefault();
DateTime? lastProcessedTime = null;
if(row != null) lastProcessedTime = row.lastProcessedTime;
```

Comment: I was sure that I will be getting a solution only from you. It happened :)  Thanks for your clear explanation and I corrected my code.

Comment: @user1671639 I have a set of email alerts that trigger when people post to any of my core projects ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell Explains why you're almost always the first answering Dapper questions - and as always in a great manner :)

Comment: @MarcGravell How can I use Dapper for parameters?  `sqlQuery="....CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@lastProcessDateTime, 101)"  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastProcessDateTime", lastProcessedTime);`

Comment: @user1671639 `DateTime lastProcessDateTime = ...; var results = conn.Query<Foo>("select * from Foo where created > @lastProcessDateTime", new { lastProcessDateTime });`

Comment: @user1671639 which is to say: the second parameter to dapper is an object; it uses the properties of that object to populate the parameters. Anonymous types (as above) make really convenient ways of expressing this, but you can also use a regular POCO type

Comment: @MarcGravell I tried as you mentioned, but not working.  `Exception: Must declare the scalar variable "@lastProcessDateTime"`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Oops, I got it. `DateTime lastProcessedTime= ...; var results = conn.Query<Foo>("select * from Foo where created > @lastProcessDateTime", new { lastProcessDateTime = lastProcessedTime});`  I just now realised, the parameterName should be equal to variable name.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1671639 if it isn't convenient to match, you can rename it in the anon-type: `DateTime when = ...;` blah blah ... `new { lastProcessDateTime = when }` - very nice